# WebSphere min heap size

Tags: websphere, size, heap-memory

There's a lot of different advice regarding heap sizes and I was interested to see what should be a general setting for min setting when max is currently set to 2048.

I thought the min should be set to about half of the max.

What could the implications of having the min set to low be?

Answer (score 0):

There are no golden rules for setting the Min and Max Heap size of your Websphere.

It depends on **how much memory your app needs** and **how much load will the specific server have**.

My suggestion is to set min heap size to a low value and max heap size to a high enough value.

Then expose the server in production-like load and read **verbose gc log (native_stderr.log)** of the JVM to see how it performs.

Generally speaking you should keep your Heap usage between **40%-70%** of your max heap Size.

Comment: Thanks for the advice will do some testing and see how it goes.